# C++ Coding with 2D Array

Tags: c++

I am trying to learn C++ and trying to write a code for a simple hash table like following structure:

```
array[0][0] array[0][1] array[0][2]
key 1        value 1      value 2

array[1][0] array[1][1] 
key 2        value 3     

array[2][0] array[2][1] array[2][2]
key 3        value 4      value 5
```

means Array of Dynamic Arrays. Now, below is my code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<conio.h>

using namespace std;

 int ele [10] ;
 int** arrays = new int*[10] ;

class HashTable
{
   public:

    HashTable()
    {    
         for(int i = 0 ; i < 10 ; i++)
         ele[i] = - 1 ;     // element array stores the number of elements in column of each row
    }

    void put(int key, int value){
         if(ele[key] == -1){
         arrays[key] = new int[1];
         arrays[key][0] = value ;  // initialize 2nd dimention
         ele[key] = 0 ; 
         }
         else{
              int num = ele[key] ;
              int temp[num + 1] ;
              for(int i = 0 ; i < num ; i++)
              temp [i] = arrays[key][i] ;
              temp[num+1] = value ;
              arrays[key] = new int[num + 1] ;
              for(int i = 0 ; i < num+1 ; i++)       // take all the elements in an temporary array and store it back
              arrays[key][i] = temp [i] ;
              ele[key] = num + 1 ;
              }

         }

};

main()
{

HashTable object;

 object.put(0 , 100);
 object.put(1 , 200);
 object.put(3 , 300);
 object.put(3 , 3000);
 object.put(3 , 30000);
 object.put(5 , 500);
 object.put(5 , 5000);
 object.put(5 , 50000);
 object.put(5 , 50); 


for (int i = 0 ; i < 10 ; i++ ){
int j = ele[i] ;

cout << j << " K ";

if(j != -1){
for (int k = -1 ; k < j ; k++ )    // print the values of corresponding keys
cout << arrays[i][k] << "  ";
}
}


 getch();
   return 0;
}
```

which uses put method to put values in the custom HashTable.

Can anybody help me why above code gives wrong output value while trying to retrieve values of the corresponding key.

Comment: I suugest that you get a good book and read a chapter on arrays ... 5 times at least. So many things are wrong in your code, that I don't know where to start. PS. This is NOT a hash table, not even near.

Comment: @aleguna, a little bit pointer will be helpful.

Comment: "why above code gives wrong output value while trying to retrieve values": what does it output?

Comment: I got stuck on above code. I will rewrite it after solving the issues.

Comment: @Raedwald It should output the value 100 for i = 0 in main, values 200, 300 for i = 1 .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can't work:

```
for (int k = -1 ; k < j ; k++ )
    cout << arrays[i][k] << "  ";
```

You cannot have arrays with negative indexes. When you enter the loop, you have `k = -1` so you try to access `arrays[i][-1]`, which won't work.

**Other recommendations:**

- The objects `arrays` and `ele` should be **members** of your class and be declared inside it (as private members)
- On the line where you write `arrays[key] = new int[num + 1]`, you forget to call `delete` on the previous object. This will cause a **memory leak**.
- You should print your `arrays` using a method inside your function (like the `put` method) and then just call it using `object.print()` (if you named it `print`)
- Testing `if(j != -1)` before the loop `for (int k = -1; k < j; k++)` is redundant: if `j == -1` you will never go into the loop anyway.